# Spring 3 Annotations with hibernate CRUD operations : @Autowired not working as expected

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-3

I'm currently using Spring 3 annotations along with hibernate 3 for the database connectivity. I also have to be using spring tiles.
My spring-servlet.xml is:

```
    <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.controller,com.xxx.dao,com.xxx.service" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
    id="viewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
    id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/plugin/impl/tiles/springtiles-defs.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

//Is this required????
<!-- <bean id="MyDAO" class="com.xxxx.MyDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="MyService" class="com.xxxx.MyServiceImpl"></bean> -->
```

My controller class :

```
@Controller
public class myController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    public myController() {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/index.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView Submit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stubs
        System.out.println(" Inside the controller ");

</beans>
```

And my serviceImpl class:

```
    @Service("MyService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{

@Autowired
MyDAO myDAO;
```

And my DaoImpl class :

```
   @Repository/*("myDAO")*/
   public class MyDAOImpl implements MyDAO{

List<String> clientList;

 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 private Session session;

 private Session currentSession() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

@Override
public List<ClientInfoBean> getClientList(String currentQrt) throws DataStoreException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (List<ClientInfoBean>) this.currentSession().
    createCriteria("Select * from myTable);
}
```

It still gives the below exceptions.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.service.MyService com.xxx.controller.MyController.MyService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxx.service.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.service.MyService com.xxx.controller.MyController.MyService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxx.service.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
>       ... 97 more
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxx.service.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
>       ... 99 more

Comment: Can you just make one parent package for that ?: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx" />`

Comment: Yes tried that as well. Still gives same error as pasted below. :(

Comment: your definitions of services and daos are in the same packages as implementation ?

Comment: Impl are in a different package and the definitions are in a different package : com.service and com.serviceImpl

Comment: `com.serviceImpl` or `com.service.impl`?

Comment: oh.. Yeah it is com.service and com.serviceImpl

Comment: So this is the problem i think. You need to define in your package-scan:  also `com.xxx.serviceImpl` and propably `com.xxx.daoImpl` Check this if its working i made an answer,

Comment: I changed it. And now it is going to the controller. Thanks. But now it is unable to find the session.  nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Comment: You need to add transaction management for your hibernate. Its all abouy spring configuration. Mark yoir service as @Transactional also when you provide spring configuration.

Comment: I added an answer please continue there if you have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is your packages:

You have definition of services and daos in: `com.xxx.service` and `com.xxx.dao`

and your implementation in: `com.xxx.serviceImpl` and `com.xxx.daoImpl`.

Add in also `<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.serviceImpl,com.xxx.daoImpl"/>`

Next problem you are facing is transactional management:

You havent defined it in spring configuration. This is an example how to do this:

```
<!-- Hibernate 3 Annotation SessionFactory Bean definition-->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${batchSize}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And after this you need to mark a method or your service implementation as `@Transactional` to make spring care of this.

Comment: If this answer is satisfied for you. Mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is clearly telling you that the bean is not configured 
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxx.service.MyService]

Can you check the case of the bean names that you given in annotations are matching with the parameter name. myService vs MyService.

Also adding a setter might be a good idea as spring can call setter to inject the dependency instead of using Reflection to inject it.

Comment: Can you please share an example to annotate and inject through setter?

Comment: And do we have to add these in the spring xml : <bean id="MyDAO" class="com.xxxx.MyDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="MyService" class="com.xxxx.MyServiceImpl"></bean>

Comment: You either need annotation based configuration or xml based, both are not needed at the same time. Here is one simple example http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/

Answer (score 1):

As you qualified your service as "MyService" , you can add qualifier as below to find it. By default spring should autowire by type , so component scan should load your service. If you are defining beans partially in xml and expecting other services to be autowired, you have to add  in your spring-servlet.xml

```
@Autowired
  @Qualifier("MyService")
    private MyService myService;
```

Also change your controller class as **MyController** instead of myController.
And **remove the constructor myController()**, spring will construct for you controller bean. Try to remove all your constructors in all your spring bean classes, spring will construct for you. For the beginning you can avoid qualifying the beans, remove the names in brackets( "MyService", "MyDao" etc....)

Comment: Do you mean to say I've add the definitions in the servlet.xml?

Comment: As you wish you can define beans fully or partially or nothing in servlet.xml . If you dont define beans in xml and use annotations like autowired, you have to tell spring to enable annotations to work, by <component-scan> , <annotation-config> and also a ContextLoaderListener in web.xml if you have any other context listeners.  And you have to use right naming of the beans like in your example you mentioned service name as "MyService" , so you need to qualify in the autowiring as above.

Comment: I've added this in web.xml : <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

Comment: OK And why is your controller class name is starting with lowercase, Try to change it to uppercase public class MyController , may be thats the reason its not finding.

Comment: See my answer above, change the controller class name to MyController and remove the constructor myController()

Comment: I added like above. And I still get the below error : Error creating bean with name 'MyController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.service.MyService com.xxx.controller.MyController.MyService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxx.service.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {.Autowired(required=true)

Answer (score 1):

When you define 
    
    `@Service("MyService")
    public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
    }`
    
or 
    
    `@Repository("MyDAO")
    public class MyDAOImpl implements MyDAO{
    }`
    
you are actually telling spring to create bean with the name "MyService" & "MyDAO"

when you define like
    
    `@Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDAO;`
    
you are asking from spring to give bean(s) with the name "myService" & "myDAO".

Since spring creates bean with the name which is different from what are you asking, it is giving the error.
You have to keep name of the bean in the @Service & @Repository annotation same as the variable name for the Interface.

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
}

private MyService myService;
```

Comment: I changed as told by you but I still get the exceptions : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.service.MyService com.xxx.controller.MyController.MyService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.xxx.dao.MyDAOImpl] for bean with name 'MyDAO' defined in ServletContext resource

Comment: can you show me the whole code of MyDAOImpl.java file

Comment: Is there anything missing?

Comment: Now, it is saying that MyDAO can't be found. You should change MyDAOImpl to @Repository("myDao")

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService
```

Instead of

```
@Service("MyService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
```